# I don't understand why digit not return but "local variable 'total' referenced before assignment" instead

Tags: python

I want write a method that asks a user to input a digit, but if the user also inputs a string it needs to ask the user to input again until the correct data is input.

-------code that shows error-------------

```
def get_total():
    try:
        total = int(input("How many people you got in total: "))
    except:
        print("Your data is invalid, please try again.")
        get_total()
    return total

x = get_total()
print(x)
```

If you type `5` directly, it will print `5`.
However if you type "`s`" first and then `5`, it will throw this error:

> "local variable 'total' referenced before assignment"

Can anyone could please tell me why?

**If I correct the code like this, it works just fine**

------code that works fine-----------------

```
def get_total():
    try:
        total = int(input("How many people you got in total: "))
        return total
    except:
        print("Your data is invalid, please try again.")
        return get_total()

x = get_total()
print(x)
```

So why does this happen?

Comment: You need the `while` loop, not recurrency.

Comment: You are returning something that hasn't been bound, there is no `total` if there was an exception. Don't use recursion to handle user input, see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658)

Comment: Next, `int()` will only ever throw `ValueError` in your scenario. Don't play Pokemon, you don't want to catch *all* exceptions. Only catch `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when in the code

```
total = int(input("How many people you got in total: "))
```

the input is not a number and `int` throws an exception the local variable `total` has not been assigned.
In the `except` part of the first version you are calling `get_total` recursively but this doesn't set the `total` variable, just returns you the result (that is ignored).

When (after this successful recursive call) you end up in your `return` statement the `total` variable is still unbound and therefore you get an exception.

The key point to understand is that calling `get_total` recursively is not a "goto". If you want a loop write a loop (e.g. using `while`), if you want recursion the use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that if you enter 5 in first try it assigns total the value of 5 and then returns it

However if you enter the value "s" the except block gets run and it goes back to the function call . Then you enter the value 5 the return statment in the second function call returns 5 and it exits the except block in the first function call.

Then it runs the return statement however the variable total doesnt exist only the value 5 exists

correct code is

```
def get_total():
    try:
        total = int(input("How many people you got in total: "))
    except:
        print("Your data is invalid, please try again.")
        total = get_total() 
    return total
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is also correct:

```
def get_total():
    while True: # prompt's the user until a correct input is given(break)
        try:
            total = int(input("How many people you got in total: "))
            break # if the input for total is int, program will break from the loop. if not, program will print an error message and this loop will execute again
        except:
            print("Your data is invalid, please try again.")
    return total

x = get_total()
print(x)
```

hope it helps

Comment: Please replace `while(True):` with `while True:`. No need for parantheses here.

Comment: @Matthias ok, you're right; it's more pythonic :)

Answer (score 0):

The error code should be modified as:

```
def get_total():
    try:
        total = int(input("How many people you got in total: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Your data is invalid, please try again.")
        total = get_total()  # assign return value back to total
    return total
```

You don't receive the returned value from the function when you called within function, so when it encounters `return total`, Python throws `UnboundLocalError`.

A better way is to use an infinite loop like following:

```
def get_total():
    while True:
        try:
            total = int(input("How many people you got in total: "))
            return total
        except ValueError:
            print("Your data is invalid, please try again.")
```

Note that it's not advised to handle all exceptions once (like `except:`). Always name the exception with `except` keyword (`ValueError` in this case).